# Loop loading UIViewControllers in storyboards

Tags: ios, storyboard, xib, uistoryboardsegue, nib

I'm using `storyboard` and i want to know if there is a way to use a `UINavigationController` to navigate from A->B->A->B and so on. The `UIViewControllers` are the same but the info loaded in each one is different.

I tried using segues but the problem is that the info loaded into the classes is not saved. So when i do A->B->A and i go back to the root, the info of root is the info loaded in the 2º A. Because i'm using `storyboards` i don't create instances of the `UIViewControllers` and i think that is the problem, i only use `[segue destinationViewController]` in `prepareForSegue`. I think that one solution would be stop using `storyboards` and use `Xibs`, because that way i would create an instance of each class every time they were loaded and that would solve my problem.

I just wanted to know if there is a way to do this using `storyboard`, because changing to `Xibs`, would need a lot of work. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you intend to only ever have one instance of `A` and one instance of `B`, make them both singletons so when the storyboard attempts to construct a new one, you just hand it back the reference to the original.

Comment: Can you clarify: do you want new instances of A and B each time, or do you want to switch between the two existing instances?

Comment: New instances each time, but i think i already solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never tried to do A -> B -> A -> B before. But I have tried to do A -> A -> A, and that doesn't work. A limitation of Storyboards is that you can't segue to another instance of the same VC.

However what you can do is pretty easy - instead of writing up the button to triggering a segue in the storyboard, wire it up to a method and push the new view controller onto the navigation stack manually.

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
   UIViewController *viewControllerA = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllerAIdentifier"];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerA];
}
```

Note that "prepareForSegue" won't get called here so you'll have to configure the new VC instance as needed.

Comment: The instances are created but when i go back it happens the same thing

Comment: My problem was elsewhere, but i'm gonna approve this answer because it answer the question above.